# c++ scope of variable

Tags: c++

I am having difficulties to remember whether in c++ a local (non static, and inside a block) variable defined in the block is destroyed or not as long as a pointer points to it, even after the execution leaves the block.
So if I created a int inside a block, and have a global pointer, and I leave the block, can my pointer still find that int?

I didn't finding a clear answer to this online, though it's probably been answered more than once, sorry about that.

Comment: for your convenience: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278859/c-dangling-pointer-question

Comment: So just to be clear, the way to get around that, is that you explicity reserve a memory space for that variable, with malloc, right ? How about more complicated variables (objects), is this still applicable ? Is the object destroyed when the execution leaves the block in which it was created ?

Comment: Yes, but you're using C++ so you should probably use new and delete (unless you're trying to preserve backwards comp. with C).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you're in **undefined behavior** territory.

I'm assuming you mean something like:

```
int* p = NULL;
{
   int x = 0;
   p = &x;
}
//p is a dangling pointer
```

If you attempt to dereference `p` after `}`, you'll run into trouble (or, worse, you won't and it will look like it's working).

You can however re-assign the pointer, so something like

```
p = new int();
```

is perfectly OK.

The following would be legal though (as an alternative to allocating dynamic memory with `new` or `malloc`):

```
int* p = NULL;
{
   static int x = 0;
   p = &x;
}
*p = 0;
```

Comment: So just to be clear, the way to get around that, is that you explicity reserve a memory space for that variable, with malloc, right ? How about more complicated variables (objects), is this still applicable ? Is the object destroyed when the execution leaves the block in which it was created ?

Comment: @bob yes, it's the same with user-defined types.

Comment: What does 'yes' refer to, there are two questions in my previous comment.

Comment: @bob: In C++, you typically want to use `new` instead of `malloc`. In particular, `malloc` only allocates memory, but `new` constructs an object in that memory. With the simple (built-in) types this doesn't matter much, but with more complex types it can become crucial. Although `new` returns a raw pointer, in most cases you'll want to store it in a smart pointer -- of which there are many varieties (e.g., `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`).

Comment: @bob yes to all 3 questions :) - use `new` to allocate memory, still applicable for more "complicated" objects, and the object is destroyed when the scope ends.

Comment: @bob or you could use a `static` variable in that block - it won't be deallocated - see edited answer.

Comment: I'm sorry there's still something I don't understand. You just said that I had to use 'new' to get around this problem. However you also said that objects created within the same scope are deleted once the execution reaches the end of the scope. Isn't that contradictory ? In the end, if I use list<int> L = new list<int>(), will L be deleted at the end of the scope, or not ?

Comment: That list looks more like C# syntax than C++.  But assuming it was C++, L would be removed at the end of the scope.  However the data pointed to by L would not be.

Comment: @bob it's not contradictoy. The pointer is created in that scope and will be go out of scope at `}`. The **memory it points to** will still be valid. In the scope you no longer have an `int` that will go out of scope, but an `int*`.

Comment: If I may ask one last question, why is it that it was not C++ syntax, MGZero ?

Comment: @bob C++ new returns a pointer in C++, so you can't assign it to an object. It's either `list<int>* L = new list<int>()` or `list<int> L = list<int>()` - this last one is redundant, a `list<int> L;` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

variables or objects defined inside a scope (a curly braces delimited block,called a statement block,a compound statement or simply a block) are called *automatic variables* because they have *automatic* lifetime,or duration.That is, the compiler *automatically* destroys them when the scope in which they are defined ends.
Generally, this happens when function bodies (local scopes) are exited:

```
void function()
{
  X obj;     // object of type X is created here
} // local scope ends here: obj is destroyed
```

if you bind a reference or a pointer to a local automatic variable,you're asking for trouble, as you're taking the address of a location in memory that's going to be freed when the function ends.Because the standard does not specify what could happen next,the behaviour is said to be undefined and the pointer is said to be *dangling*:

```
X *ptr=nullptr;

void function()
{
  X obj;
  ptr=&obj;
}  // obj is destroyed here: what does ptr points to now??
```

when you dynamically allocate memory (through the keyword *new*) you're not creating a local object that's going to be done with by the compiler when the scope is exited, but an object whose lifetime is decided by the code you write.
You're responsible for creating it AND you're in charge of its disposal, which you preform calling *delete* on a pointer to it.

```
X *ptr=nullptr;

void function()
{
  ptr=new X;
}  // nothing is destroyed here: ptr still points to an (unnamed) object of type X
```

It doesn't matter the type of the object,this equally applies to a primitive,or built-in type and to a user-defined,or class type.