# Returning a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I don't understand how this example can possibly work:

```
double * GetSalary()  {
  double salary = 26.48; 
  return &salary;
}

main() {
    cout << *GetSalary();  //prints 26.48

}
```

`salary` is a local variable in `GetSalary()`, thus after returning from the function, this cell might possibly be overwritten by another function.
I don't see how returning a pointer to a local variable (not instanciated on the heap) can ever possibly work.

Comment: Yes, it might possibly be overwritten. Or it might not. That's why this is called **undefined behavior**, rather than a **guaranteed crash**.

Comment: its funny that the obove code is the first result when I google "returning pointer form a function"

Comment: I often get the same thing. I have the idea that Google changes your search bubble when you're logged in to SO with a Google account.

Comment: @larsmans: I have got my question as first result (in few minutes), on a different browser (i.e not logged in google/stackoverflow)!

Comment: @VinayakGarg: ok, then I'm just being paranoid :)

Comment: @larsmans google changes the results of search based on many many things that their algorithms learn about you. While it may not be quite as simple as they bump questions to the top of the results because you are logged in to SO, I would bet money that your search results have been manipulated in such a way to make it (hopefully) more likely that you will find what their computers think you want.

Comment: @Tim: I know about learning to rank, I work in that area of research. I just don't know the features and settings of the Google algorithm :)

Comment: @larsmans I am just about convinced that no single human is even capable of knowing everything that goes into the "magic" behind their algorithms. I think the level of complexity might be beyond something that a single person could comprehend all of it. =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't work. It is undefined behaviour. It may seem to work, because "correct behaviour" is a subset of "any possible behaviour".

Answer (score 8):

You're running into undefined behavior, which means **anything can happen**. Including appearing to work.

Outside the function, the return pointer is dangling (i.e. the memory it points to is invalid).

Why it appears to work boils down to the implementation. Most probably the memory isn't cleared. So although you don't have access to what the return pointer points to, in that memory the `26.48` still exists. But it's just by chance.

Answer (score 2):

```
double * GetSalary()  
{   
     double salary = 26.48;    
     return &salary; 
}  
double dummy_function()
{
     double a = 1.1;
     double b = 2.2;
     double c = 0 , d = 0;

     c = a + b - d;
     return c;  
}

main() 
{     
     double *a;
     a = GetSalary();
     cout << dummy_function();
     cout << *a;  //this time it wont print 26.48
}
```

Because function stack has been overwritten by the second function call `dummy_function`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't "work", it's dereferencing a pointer that is no longer valid. That the memory pointed at happens to hold the expected value is not a sign of the program as a whole "working" or being correct.

To understand why it happens to work, you need to analyze the exact pattern of stack frame shifts that take place, which is kind of annoying, and very compiler-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) which invokes [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
on some systems it might crash your application, on others it might appear to work correctly. But either way, you should not do it.
see [this similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278859/c-dangling-pointer-question).

Answer (score 0):

This also works, but is much safer. It won't work right in a multi-threaded program.

```
double * GetSalary()  {
  static double salary = 26.48; 
  return &salary;
}
```